# Eclipse: Welcome to Modelica Development Tooling (MDT) Console - empty reply:

Tags: eclipse, openmodelica, eclipse-mdt

I'm doing my first steps in OpenModelica, and have trouble to get the MDT running in eclipse.

*) OpenModelica v1.18.0 (64-bit) installed

*) Installation MDT in eclispes done according to: https://openmodelica.org/doc/OpenModelicaUsersGuide/latest/mdt.html

*) Modelica project generated, with first demo function.

```
model demo
   Real x(start=1);
   parameter Real a = 1;
   
equation
  dev(x) = -a*x;
end demo;
```

*) I state an OpenModelica Console and try to simulate.  This is my feedback.

```
Welcome to Modelica Development Tooling (MDT) Console
You can send commands to OMC from here.
Type !help for help.
omc> !help
omc> reply:

omc> simulate(demo,stopTime=2)
omc> reply:

omc> plot(x)
omc> reply:

omc>
```

*) **The Problem:** So starting the Consoel seems to work. Hoever no feedback is shown. Also no window with plot is shown.

**Things checked:**

- OPENMODELICAHOME=C:\Program Files\OpenModelica1.18.0-64bit\ ... seems to be correct

**Further Info**

OpenModelica v1.18.0 (64-bit)

Eclipse Platform, Version: 2021-09 (4.21), Build id: I20210906-0500

Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19042.1288]

Comment: I would suggest you use OMEdit instead of MDT as it has much better support for Modelica. If you still want to use MDT, look in the Error log to find the error message. You can also report an issue here: https://github.com/OpenModelica/MDT but we don't really have the resources to work on MDT too much.

Comment: Hello Aldrian.  Agree. I have switched to OMEdit. (The reason, why i tried MDT was because initially I didn't find the TextView window in OMEdit. I got the wrong impression that OMEdit is just for drag&drop  modelling and not for coding.  Now that I have found this feature don't need MDT anymore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested by Aldrian:
OMEdit is the better tool for my requirements. So issue on MDT does not affect me anymore.  Question closed.